# Displaying data using MySQL class in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I know how to display data without using class, but i have been asked to use mysql class instead. It seems that i have to initiate the class and just use the written functions, but whatever i try to display - it doesn't work. All i am getting is "Resource id #14", which means that everything should be good with the connection. Please help!

**This is a part of the MySQL class:**

```
class SQL //MySQL
{
  var $link_id;
  var $query_result;
  var $num_queries = 0;

  function connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name = '', $use_names = '', $pconnect = false, $newlink = true) {

    if ($pconnect) $this->link_id = @mysql_pconnect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password);
    else $this->link_id = @mysql_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password, $newlink);
        if (!empty($use_names)) $this->query("SET NAMES '$use_names'");

    if ($this->link_id){
      if($db_name){
        if (@mysql_select_db($db_name, $this->link_id)) return $this->link_id;
          else die(mysql_error());// = "Can't open database ('$db_name')";
        if (!empty($use_names)) $this->query("SET NAMES '$use_names'");
      }
    } else die(mysql_error());// = "Can't connect to mysql server";
  }

  function db($db_name) {
    if ($this->link_id){
      if (@mysql_select_db($db_name, $this->link_id)) return $this->link_id;
        else die(mysql_error());// = "Can't open database ('$db_name')";
    } else die(mysql_error());// = "Can't connect to database";
  }

  function query($sql){
    $this->query_result = @mysql_query($sql, $this->link_id);

    if ($this->query_result){
      ++$this->num_queries;
      return $this->query_result;
    } else {
        $error = "
            <pre>
                QUERY: \n {$sql} \n\n
                ERROR: <span style=\"color:red\">" . mysql_error() . " </span>
            </pre>
        ";
      die($error);
    }
  }
  function result($query_id = 0, $row = 0, $field = NULL){
    return ($query_id) ? @mysql_result($query_id, $row, $field) : false;
  }

  function fetch_row($query_id = 0){
    return ($query_id) ? @mysql_fetch_row($query_id) : false;
  }

  function fetch_array($query_id = 0){
    return ($query_id) ? @mysql_fetch_array($query_id) : false;
  }

  function fetch_assoc($query_id = 0){
    return ($query_id) ? @mysql_fetch_assoc($query_id) : false;
  }

  function num_rows($query_id = 0){
    return ($query_id) ? @mysql_num_rows($query_id) : false;
  }
....
```

**and my php code:**

```
<?php
require_once('C:/wamp/www/smarty-3.1.21/libs/Smarty.class.php');
include('C:/wamp/www/smarty-3.1.21/libs/Mysql.class.php');

$smarty = new Smarty();
$smarty->enableSecurity();

$smarty->setTemplateDir('C:\wamp\www\forum\templates');
$smarty->setCompileDir('C:\wamp\www\forum\templates_c');
$smarty->setConfigDir('C:\wamp\www\forum\configs');
$smarty->setCacheDir('C:\wamp\www\forum\cache');

$db = new SQL();
$db->connect('localhost','root','','job', '', false, true);

$db->db('job');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM job";
$db->query($sql);
$output = $db->query_result;
$result = $db->fetch_row();


$smarty->assign('rez', $result);
$smarty->assign('output', $output);
$smarty->display('index.tpl');

?>
```

Comment: don't use mysql_* functions (expecially with @) - use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: Well, yes, but i have got the job to learn and use that specific MySQL class.

Comment: Is it in the `$output` smarty variable you're seeing the Resource? That appears to be because you use `$smarty->assign('output', $output);` when you mean to use `$smarty->assign('output', $result);` to assign the result of `fetch_row()`. The variable `$output` is the result resource object from a `mysql_query()` call.

Comment: No, i display both the $result (which is $rez in the template) and $output (which is also $output in the template). $rez displays nothing.